# MSAL silent authentication using SSO from one app to another in flutter (iOS)

Tags: flutter, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

I would really appreciate if any help me with the issue that I am facing. I am using MSAL authentication in swift to initially authenticate user using MS service broker. This is working fine. I would like to use the same authentication and silently log into another application through web view in flutter which is where I am having problem. When I open another application in webview in flutter its redirecting to authentication page. What parameters should I set so that subsequent redirects in webview should not ask for authentication and log in silently?

Swift code
'''
private func acquireToken(scopes: [String], result: @escaping FlutterResult)
{
print(scopes)
if let application = getApplication(result: result){
let viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController.keyViewController!
let webviewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: viewController)
webviewParameters.webviewType = .default

```
          print("WebView Value Type: %i", webviewParameters.webviewType.rawValue );
          if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
              webviewParameters.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = false
          }

          removeAccount(application)

          let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: scopes, webviewParameters: webviewParameters)

          application.acquireToken(with: interactiveParameters, completionBlock: { (msalresult, error) in
          guard let authResult = msalresult, error == nil else {
                  result(FlutterError(code: "AUTH_ERROR", message: "Authentication error", details: error!.localizedDescription))
                  return
              }
              
              result(self.getResultLogin(authResult))

          })

      }
      else {
          return
      }

  }
```

}
'''
Authentication is working fine. Now when I use flutter_inappwebview package in flutter to open another application which has same client ID, Its redirecting me to log in page instead of using the already logged in session. Its only happening in iOS, Android is working fine.

it was mentioned in flutter_inappwebview package in iOS uses ASWebAuthenticationSession, which will maintain the authentication session. So I have used the sample example they have given in their page to open another web application in webview. This is the flutter code

InAppWebView(
key: webViewKey,
initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.url)),
initialOptions: options,
pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
webViewController = controller;
},
onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
logger.d("printing webview controller type: " +
controller.runtimeType.toString());

```
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url.toString();
                    urlController.text = this.url;
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
                androidOnPermissionRequest:
                    (controller, origin, resources) async {
                  return PermissionRequestResponse(
                      resources: resources,
                      action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                },
                shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                    (controller, navigationAction) async {
                  var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                  if (![
                    "http",
                    "https",
                    "file",
                    "chrome",
                    "data",
                    "javascript",
                    "about"
                  ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                      // Launch the App
                      await launch(
                        url,
                      );
                      // and cancel the request
                      return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                    }
                  }

                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                },
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                  pullToRefreshController?.endRefreshing();
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url.toString();
                    urlController.text = this.url;
                  });
                },
                onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                  pullToRefreshController?.endRefreshing();
                },
                onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                  if (progress == 100) {
                    pullToRefreshController?.endRefreshing();
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    this.progress = progress / 100;
                    urlController.text = this.url;
                  });
                },
                onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.url = url.toString();
                    urlController.text = this.url;
                  });
                },
                onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                  print(consoleMessage);
                },
              ),
```

When I open the inappwebview in my flutter applications, Its asking for log in again. What should tweak so that it will not ask for another log in and use the initial log in session in this webview.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Suneel